# Iterating over a parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

I have a parameter pack `args...` of vectors of arbitrary types, corresponding to which there is a vector of indices say `v = {3,0,5...}` having the same size, and order as the number of members of `args...`. I would like `get_tuple` to return a tuple of the elements of `args...` at the indices given by `v`.

Here's what I have so far, but I'm stuck trying to iterate over the members of the parameter pack.

```
template<typename... Args>
auto get_tuple(const std::vector<size_t>& vector, const Args &... args) {
    return std::make_tuple(args[v[0]]...);
}
```

For example:

```
std::vector<std::string> v1 = {"a", "b"};
std::vector<int> v2 = {1,2};
std::vector<size_t> v = {0,1};
auto result = get_tuple(v, v1, v2); // ("a",2) expected
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++17, you need additional level of indirection to get a pack of indices to get a pack of elements at those indices:

```
template<typename... Args, std::size_t... Is>
auto get_tuple_impl(const std::vector<std::size_t>& indices,
                    std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                    const Args&... args) {
    return std::make_tuple(args[indices[Is]]...);
}

template<typename... Args>
auto get_tuple(const std::vector<std::size_t>& indices, const Args&... args) {
    return get_tuple_impl(indices, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>(), args...);
}
```

In C++20, we could you a lambda function with template parameters invoked in-place:

```
template<typename... Args>
auto get_tuple(const std::vector<std::size_t>& indices, const Args&... args) {
    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::make_tuple(args[indices[Is]]...);
    }(std::index_sequence_for<Args...>());
}
```

You might also want to add an assertion `assert(indices.size() == sizeof...(Args));` or use `std::array<std::size_t, N>` type instead.

Comment: Small note, `std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>` is equivalent to `std::index_sequence_for<Args...>`. I might as well also mention that C++20 makes this technique a bit less ugly with templated lambdas.

Comment: @chris would you care to provide the C++20 solution that you have in mind? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @marital_weeping, It is indeed almost character-for-character what's in the answer now.